# equivalent to {isGesture: true/false} on apple map for react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Anyone an Idea for a equal-function to {isGesture: boolean} for apple maps on react-native-maps?

I need to differentiate, if the user do a gesture or the movement comes from an animation, like animateToRegion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use onPanDrag to identify where a user is causing the map to move? I would suggest you use that:

```
     <MapView
      ...
      onPanDrag={
        ({nativeEvent: {coordinate: { latitude, longitude }}}) => {
          console.log("user dragged map to lat:", latitude, "lng:", longitude);
         }
      }
      />
```

That idea comes from a [an issue thread in the repo](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3631#issuecomment-860701921), all I searched for was 'isGesture'.

Otherwise I would say to implement the logic you need wherever you're using animateToRegion. You'd have to implement that feature on your own, probably using something from the [handling map events article for mapkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/mapkit/map/handling_map_events).

This is also mentioned in a feature request for the library: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3952#issuecomment-923173197.